# Strong name signed assembly is invalid when ported to VS2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, code-signing, strongname

I just ported my CPP and C# projects from VS2008 to VS2010. I used the conversion wizard to convert all my projects. The issue i face is i get an error "**../Mydll.dll is a strong-name signed assembly and embedding a manifest invalidates the signature. You will need to re-sign this file to make it a valid assembly.**" . What does this mean and how to sign CPP a dll in VS2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to sign a C++ CLI assembly in VS 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656412/is-there-an-easy-way-to-sign-a-c-cli-assembly-in-vs-2010)