# C++/CLI assembly signing issue - VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an issue where C++/CLI projects are attempting to strong name sign the resulting assembly by setting Linker->Advanced->Key File (causing the linker command line to specify /KEYFILE:"keyfilename.snk"). The build runs FxCop on the output assembly as a post-build step; this step warns: "warning : CA2210 : Microsoft.Design : Verify that 'assemblyName.dll' has a valid strong name before deploying.". When I use sn.exe to verify (sn -v assemblyName.dll) it warns that "assemblyName.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly". I just noticed that in the (build) debug output directory, there is a link.command.1.tlog file, and there the link statement shows that the linker is being run with /DELAYSIGNED on the command line! I've tried setting Linker->Advanced->Delay Sign explcictly to "No (/DELAYSIGN:NO)" (previously this was empty), but this hasn't changed the link statement in the link.command.1.tlog file; problem still remains. When I look at the linker command line in the project properties, it shows this:
/OUT:"..........\binaries\Debug\Imaging.Utilities.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /DLL "C:\engineering\ReusableComponents\BaseUtils\Debug\BaseUtils.lib" "C:\engineering\ReusableComponents\VendorSpecificUtils\LeadUtils\Debug\LeadUtils.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"...\Debug\Imaging.Utilities.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\engineering\binaries\Debug\Imaging.Utilities.pdb" /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /FIXED:NO /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /KEYFILE:"c:\Engineering\RC.Net\Core\Code\InternalKey.snk" /DELAYSIGN:NO /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

I have read and applied the work-around discussed here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx

The .snk file used on the linker command line is the same one used in other projects in the same solution, which are C# assemblies, and they are correctly strongly signed.

I'm using VS 2010, SP1.

Any ideas what is happening here? How can I get the linker command line to be correct (either not include /DELAYSIGN, or use /DELAYSIGN:NO)? Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to sign a C++ CLI assembly in VS 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656412/is-there-an-easy-way-to-sign-a-c-cli-assembly-in-vs-2010)

Comment: I fixed this by applying ALL the changes listed in: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx

Comment: @wonone: Updated Link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/proposed-workaround-for-ccli-assembly-signing-issue-with-vs2010-sp1/